# Kubuntu 22.10 wifi hotspot not visible

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager

I tried to set up a wifi hotspot on my laptop so that my android phone can use. My laptop's wifi card support AP. I first used plasma-nm's "create Hotspot" button on the system tray to create a hotspot, the hotspot didn't show up in my cell phone'd wifi searching. I then used network manager's commandline tool to setup a hotspot with  `nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp2s0 ssid myssid password "mypassword"` , still nothing showed up in my phone's wifi list. I made sure that hotspot is not hidden. Please help me

My wireles adapter is Intel Wireless-AC 9260

Comment: what's in the output of `nmcli dev wifi` in cmd window?